# Tooltip set in ASP.net by method in c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

trying to get same string on tooltip as is in the "Text" e.g.
Text="<%# methodname(parameter) %>"
 
ToolTip="<%# methodname(parameter) %>" - this however errors out

- Text is not static - dependent on string returned in method

  ```
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Header" runat="server" Text="<%# methodname(parameter) %>"
  meta:resourcekey="HeaderResource1"></asp:Label>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  ```

any help would be really appreciated

```
protected string methodname(int integer)
{
    switch (integer)
    {
        case 1:
            return RadtxtLot1.Text.Trim();
        case 2:
            return RadtxtLot2.Text.Trim();
        case 3:
            return RadtxtLot3.Text.Trim();
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: how your methodname looks like??

Comment: The methodname is returning a string - which is then set as the column header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something in your code behind like setting the Tooptip equal to the Text of the Label in your preRender stage.

Or another less tidy way would be to make your label a ReadOnly TextBox and attach a method on it "OnTextChanged" then set the Tooltip in that... if you don't mind that field looking like a text box.